# add options for select wordpress php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using theme: Motors
I want to add select with options for admin panel.
options should be: `'-', 'eletro', 'auto'`
I've already added select but it's empty:

```
    $manager->register_control(
        'autofilling',
        array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'section' => 'stm_options',
            'preview' => 'autofilling',
            'label' => esc_html__( 'Autofilling', 'stm_vehicles_listing' ),
            'attr' => array( 'class' => 'widefat' )
        )
    );
```

I tried to write `'options'=> "['-', 'eletro', 'auto']",` but it didn't work.
I also tried:

```
 'options' => [
                    '-' => __( '-', 'stm_vehicles_listing' ),
                    'electro' => __( 'electro', 'stm_vehicles_listing' ),
                    'auto' => __( 'auto', 'stm_vehicles_listing' ),
                ],
```

and:

```
        'options' => [
            '-' => '-',
            'electro' => 'electro',
            'auto' => 'auto',
        ],
```

Maybe I can add them with DB? But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You need to use `choices` instead of `options`.

```
$manager->register_control(
    'autofilling',
    array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'section' => 'stm_options',
        'preview' => 'autofilling',
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Autofilling', 'stm_vehicles_listing' ),
        'attr' => array( 'class' => 'widefat' ),
        'choices' => array(
            'default' => __( '-', 'stm_vehicles_listing' ),
            'electro' => __( 'electro', 'stm_vehicles_listing' ),
            'auto' => __( 'auto', 'stm_vehicles_listing' ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think your answer will help a lot of people, because  I couldn't find anything in the internet and my colleagues didn't know how to do this too!

Comment: Glad to help you @Alex. :)

Comment: you got `x` in default option, BTW

Comment: do you know how to add onchange to it?

Comment: can  I just write `'onchange' => 'auto()'(not working)` or something? I'm using `stm_vehicles_listing` plugin

Comment: I dont have your theme or plugin. how to test?

Comment: ok, how can I add onchange with JS? I did that for old project but I forgot how to do this

Comment: use onchange in jquery